# SQL Server : whole number without rounding Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running below query I am expecting value of **300** (I am getting in Excel).
I want to get value 300 without rounding.

```
declare @a decimal(20, 10)

set @a = (1.00000 / 33.00000)

select @a

select @a * 9900 (0.0303030303 * 9900 = 300 in Excel).
```

In SQL Server, the result is 299.9999. I want to get 300 without rounding. I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: It is Excel who is rounding the result. While 0,0303030303 * 9900 can be 300 in Excel, it is 299,99999997 according to the math. So getting 300 *without rounding* is impossible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "without rounding"?   What do you think the word "rounding" means?   Did you try adding `0.0001`?

Comment: Your statement about Excel is wrong, at least in 2010. Enter `=0.0303030303 * 9900` into cell `A1`, and enter `=A1 - 300` in cell `A2`. Note that `A2` does not display zero.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out Excel is rounding the numbers.  To round in SQL there are several functions you can use:

1. [Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175003.aspx)
2. [Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189818.aspx)
3. [Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178531.aspx)

Ceiling rounds up, floor down and round to the nearest.  With round you have to specify how many decimal places you wish to round to.

**Example**

```
SELECT
    CEILING(1.5)    AS c,
    FLOOR(1.5)      AS f,   
    ROUND(1.5, 0)   AS r
;
```

**Returns**

```
c   f   r
2   1   2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the digits of precision are decided by your denominator. For example:

```
SELECT 1/1
```

This will return 1.

```
SELECT 1/1.0
```

This will return 1.000000.

In this case, since you divide by 33.00000, your answer will have decimal precision. I think you could `ROUND` your result if you'd like. The below query will give you your intended results.

`SELECT CAST(ROUND(299.99999, -1) AS INT)`

As other users have said, SQL Server is giving the correct answer, despite what Excel shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast or convert for this:

```
declare @a decimal(20,10) set @a=(1.00000/33.00000) select @a select CONVERT (INT, @a * 9900)
```

OR

```
declare @a decimal(20,10) set @a=(1.00000/33.00000) select @a select CAST(@a * 9900 AS INT)
```

Comment: That's nice but the OP stated they expected to get 300. Unless you round this you will get 299.

Comment: Thansk randy and sean I think Sql server will give 299.In another case 0.0303030303 * 2870 I need 86 not 87 If I round 0.0303030303 * 9900 will give 300 and 0.0303030303 * 2870 will give 87(where I want 86) I want to confirm whether I can be able to do it in sqlserver.

Comment: @user2107843 in excel `=0.0303030303*2870` will show you `86.9697` unlike `=0.0303030303*9900` that shows `300`. SQL Server shows much more accurate answer on your formulas.